# Cannot install gem 'chartkick' on vs code on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems, codespaces

I installed the gem 'chartkick' on codespace correctly using the instructions from https://github.com/ankane/chartkick. I didn't use only yarn add chartkick chart.js and import "chartkick/chart.js" for Webpacker. When on a new project on vs code on windows 11 I try to install the gem 'chartkick' I keep seeing loading for any chart data. When I executed the yarn add chartkick chart.js command, I got something like this:

```
yarn : File C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on
  system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=13517
0.
At line:1 char:1
+ yarn add chartkick chart.js
+ ~~~~
     + CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I tried npm install chartkick chart.js and this command started but I still see loading.

Comment: Hi @Coder1234 - as a general rule of thumb in programming, trying to understand what the error is from the traceback and googling it is hugely helpful. I'd recommend you try googling something along the lines of `scripts is disabled on
  system windows`. I see that there are several answers to this question, hopefully one of them works for you

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your ExecutionPolicy in PowerShell is restricted.

To change this, open Powershell.
Run the following command:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

See if you get back the message "Restricted".

If this is the case, run the following command in PowerShell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

You probably have to confirm this with a yes.

Afterwards you should be able to run such scripts on your PC.